# problem with encoding when using jspf

Tags: java, encoding, arabic, jspinclude, jsp-fragments

When I include jspf inside jsp page such as:

```
<jsp:include page="anyJSPF.jspf">
```

the encoding of all Arabic contents has been unreadable. Where can I set encoding style to UTF-8 when including jspf?

I need to know the solution, please some body help !

Comment: i tried to edit my question, but the coding does not appear,plz can someone edit my question?

Comment: Formatting rules appear in right hand column while you edit the message.

Comment: @BalusC many thanx:) but why ' appears, i think it shouldn't!!

Comment: @Alaa: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebI18N5.html

Comment: @MattBall can u tell me what u have done to make a good view of the cod?

Comment: @Alaa: hit the "edit" button and you can see the raw input. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Basically, indent blocks of code by 4 spaces, or 1 tab; use backticks (`\``) to delineate sections of inline code, `like <this/>`.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered indirectly in this question [Error in includign jspf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874250/error-in-includign-jspf) , when I use

```
<%@include file="anyJSPF.jspf" %>
```

the encoding problem is fixed, thanx to @BalusC for his answer.