# Error in includign jspf

Tags: java, jsp, include, jsp-fragments

I want to make include jspf into index jsp page , these statements

```
<%-- any content can be specified here e.g.: --%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

aappears in the index page !!

here's the include line in index page

```
 <jsp:include page="WEB-INF/jspf/Header.jspf" />
```

Note : 
I make head and body in the index page only, can some body tell me why the first lines appears in the index page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSPF files are intented to be statically included by `@include`. Its source code becomes then literally part of the parent JSP file. This happens only once, during compiletime.

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/Header.jspf" %>
```

If you want a compiletime include with `<jsp:include>` then just rename `.jspf` to `.jsp`. The source code will then be compiled once separately and its output will be generated and included during runtime. This happens then on every request.

Comment: It works and fix the Arabic encoding problem too, I don't think making the include for header and footer at compile time r not good practice, what do u think Mr @BalusC ?